# set/getCorrelationIdString not working

Tags: spring-amqp

It was surprising to me Set/getCorrelationIdString is not workng for me. It is 
amqp-client 3.6.5 and other spring-rabbit/amqp 1.6.6.Anybody else faced it ?  I am surviving with Set/getCorrelationId which works but shows as depreciated. Any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter` has default strategy as:

```
private volatile CorrelationIdPolicy correlationIdPolicy = CorrelationIdPolicy.BYTES;
```

For backward compatibility.

If you wish to use `Set/getCorrelationIdString`, you should inject `DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter` into `RabbitTemplate` and `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` with the `CorrelationIdPolicy.STRING`.

Comment: Then why Set/getCorrelationId got depreciated ? Any Idea

Comment: Just because the `AMQP.BasicProperties` supports only `String` for `correlationId`. So, no reason to convert to `byte[]` and back to `String`

Comment: Starting with version `2.0` Spring AMQP doesn't provide that confuse any more. And `get/setCorrelationId` are only for `String`.